# How to set context with docker-compose and multiple dockerfiles

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, docker-compose

I'm having trouble getting docker-compose to work with an express backend and a create-react-app frontend. (With prisma and a database along for the ride) The problem seems to be that I run docker-compose from a parent folder and even though I specify the frontend and backend as context under build, it appears to run in the parent context.

This means that first of all, any packages like webpack that I have installed as dev-dependencies I can't call unless I run them globally, but the main problem is that since they run from the parent context, things like webpack get confused because they can't find my dist directory because their base directory is the parent instead of the child. How can I fix this? Context doesn't seem to work.

```
version: '3'
services:
  ...
  #prisma and postgres details
  ...
  backend:
    restart: always
    container_name: backend
    build:
      context: ./backend
    ports:
      - '4000:4000'
    links:
      - prisma
    depends_on:
      - prisma
    volumes:
      - ./backend:/app
  frontend:
    restart: always
    container_name: frontend
    build:
      context: ./frontend
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
    links:
      - backend
    depends_on:
      - backend
    volumes:
      - ./frontend:/app
```

Here is my backend/package.json file. Weirdly, I have to install a bunch of npm packages globally because apparently the CMD isn't running it from the right context. The docker: start command is: `prisma deploy && concurrently "webpack --watch --mode development" "nodemon dist/main.js"`

```
FROM mhart/alpine-node:8.11.3
USER root

RUN mkdir -p /app
WORKDIR /app

RUN npm config set unsafe-perm true

COPY package.json /app/package.json
RUN npm install
RUN npm install -g prisma nodemon concurrently webpack webpack-cli

COPY . /app
CMD ["npm", "run", "docker:start"]
```

Here is my frontend dockerfile, npm start is the `react-scripts start` command.

```
FROM mhart/alpine-node:8.11.3
USER root

RUN mkdir -p /app
WORKDIR /app

RUN npm config set unsafe-perm true
RUN npm install -g react-scripts

COPY package.json /app
RUN npm install
COPY . /app
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```